# Basic probability theory problem

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> A fair coin is tossed until a head or 5 tails occurs. Find the
>   expected number $E$ of the tosses of a coin. Find its probability
>   distribution function. Find its cumulative distribution function.

Here's my attempt:

We approach this problem in a more general case, i.e., suppose the probabality the coin, when tossed, results to a head is $p$. Now, let $X$ be the number tosses until a head or 5 tails occurs. Then, our sample space is
$$
 \Omega = \{H,\ TH,\ TTH,\ TTTH,\ TTTTH,\ TTTTT\}
$$
and, thus, $X$ assumes values $1,2,3,4,5$. Observe that multiplicative and additive property of probability imply the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}[X=1] &= \mathbb{P}[\{H\}] = p\\
  \mathbb{P}[X=2] &= \mathbb{P}[\{TH\}] = (1-p)p\\
  \mathbb{P}[X=3] &= \mathbb{P}[\{TTH\}] = (1-p)^2p\\
  \mathbb{P}[X=4] &= \mathbb{P}[\{TTTH\}] = (1-p)^3p\\
  \mathbb{P}[X=5] &= \mathbb{P}[\{TTTTH, TTTTT\}] = (1-p)^4p + (1-p)^5 = (1-p)^4(2-p)
\end{align*}
$$
Written more compactly,
$$
 \mathbb{P}[X=n] = 
 \begin{cases}
  (1-p)^{n-1}\,p\qquad\quad\ \text{if}\quad n=1,2,3,4\\[12pt]
  (1-p)^4(2-p)\qquad \text{if}\quad n=5\\
 \end{cases}
$$
When $p=\frac{1}{2}$, the above distribution reduces to the following special case:
$$
 \mathbb{P}[X=n] = 
 \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2^n}\qquad \text{if}\quad n=1,2,3,4\\[12pt]
  \frac{3}{2^5}\qquad \text{if}\quad n=5\\
 \end{cases}
$$

**But** at this point I have realized that the resulting expression is **NOT** a probability mass function. Maybe I have missed something like possibly my sample space is wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: in $\mathbb{P}[X = 5]$, you made a small mistake. $(1-p)^4p + (1-p)^5 = (1-p)^4(p + 1 - p) = (1-p)^4$.

Comment: WOW! That's it! Thank you @DWe1.